# How to start Login Activity if user wasn't active for 5 minutes:

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, onresume

I need to start the log in `Activity` if the user wasn't active for 5 minutes in the application 
,without considering from what activity he left the application. (by not active for 5 minutes I mean that the user didn't commit any action to the server side)

I have a `Date` variable inside my `Application` class:

```
private Date timeOfLogin;
```

that's is saved when the user commits log in, in some point of usage the user can get a phone call or
a mail and will leave the application. now this can happen on any screen of the application. And now when he turns on the application again /return to it after finishing his phone call I need to show the log in screen again and not his last activity if 5 or more minutes have passed.

How can it be done? do I have to override every `onResume` of each activity I have in the application and start the log in `Activity` if the difference between the `timeOfLogin` and current date is bigger then 5 minutes? or is there a better way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: define one timer for activity touch listener and reset your counter when user do something.

Comment: You can use service to check every if user commits action every 5 minutes

Comment: by active i mean there was no interaction with the server, not necessarily with the application. so the last user touch event is not that important.

Comment: @Raghunandan, and what would i do in the service if the user didn't commit action the last 5 minutes? can you give a more explanatory example?

Comment: Or Use a broadcast receiver. Broadcast if user does not commit in 5 minutes. Register a receiver in your activities. If you receive a broadcast pop a dialog asking for user to login or navigate to login page. Just an idea. I have not tried this.

Comment: All communication with your server is through a network connection class?

Comment: No, all communication to my server is through AsyncTasks that are fired at specific locations. while the response handling is all done in a ResponseHandler class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an activity that all of your other activities extend and put the logic in that activity's onResume. (You'll probably find this practice to be useful in a lot of other ways too)

Comment: this actually can be a solution, and I will eventually go with it if I don't find any other way. but for now I'm trying to avoid the overriding of onResume in all activities and looking for a more elegant solution if it's exists.

Comment: the answer is not overriding the resume on all activities. The answer is to override in one activity and have the other activities extend it. That sounds to me like a proper object orientated solution.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the final result is that I will override all onResume methods in all activities because all of them will extend this activity. in case i have FragmentActivities in my application then I should create this kind of a shallow object for FragmentActivity as well. for now I think that I should avoid it and wonder if there is a more elegant solution for the problem

Comment: I always do as adonal3 suggested, in all my apps. This time you need the onResume, next time you will need onDestroy, onCreate or common methods like hideKeyboard().
Don't worry if you have a FragmentActivity that has no fragments. if 90% of your activities use fragments, I would make them all inherit from the same myFragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

Create a `CountDownTimer` with 5 minute count down in your ResponseHandler class in the `onFinish()` show the `login` dialog. If there is any response cancel the timer and start again.

Comment: sound like an interesting solution could you please explain it a little bit more? what do you mean by onFinish()? ResponseHandler is not an activity it's s simple java class, and it's not controlling all the other activities so even if the timer counter is finished and I will fire the login screen intent. pressing the back button by the user will bring him back to his previous activity.

Comment: The countdown timer has onTick and onFinish methods. onFinish is called when the duration expired. You can override onBackPress and show your dialog again or kill your task.

Comment: I just wrote a test app with a class call Countdown, in that class I have a countdown timer and in the constructor I start it. Even when I exist my application the timer is still sticking. So I think my solution will work. You made your login screen single instance and onFinish you kill the other task in your app if possible.