# How properly handle server communication in Android:

Tags: android, session, android-asynctask

In my application I am working a lot with server communication and the deal is like this:

At first I have to make a call to a server to get a unique ID (`GUID`, or I think it's called `UUID` in java). after that I can perform other operations with the server while I have to send the received Id with my operation. the problem is that this session is valid for only 5 minutes of inactivity after that I need to get a new Id from the server.

So if the user quits the application and wasn't active then I just send him back to the log in screen to authenticate again and to receive a new unique Id from the server when he gets back to my application by overriding the `onResume` method in all of my `Activities`:

[How to start Login Activity if user wasn't active for 5 minutes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661557/how-to-start-login-activity-if-user-wasnt-active-for-5-minutes)

**The Question:** But what if the user using the application for 5 minutes and in this time he never makes any call to the server, his Id becomes invalid and the next his call to the server returns id invalid message.

So I could do some thing like this (pseudo-code):

```
class SessionInvalidAwareMethod(AsyncTask task)
{
    AsyncTask currentAsyncTask = task;
    AsyncTask authenticateAsyncTask;

    public SomeResult executeTask()
    {
        result = executeCurrentAsyncTask();
        if (result = sessionInvalid)
        { 
            executeAuthenticationTask()
            result = executeCurrentAsyncTask();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**The Problem:** But I would like to avoid the call to the server and getting the session invalid message.
So I hold Date parameter in my application class that hold for me the last time I go my id from the server. how could I use it to decide depending on how much time has passed if I should run the current `AsyncTask` or run the `authenticateAsyncTask` first and only after it's finished I should run the current `AsyncTask` (`My problem is to do the second step in a synchronous way`)?

can some one explain to me what is the right way to handle this kind of situations overall?

Thanks for your help friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the server handle the session using cookies. It will have a login/logout calls in its API. 
The client will use the login/logout calls accoding to the app needs (i.e. Activity timeout). The client can get the login status from the cookie.

If you don't have control over the server sessions timeout, you can make a keep-alive service that will make an empty call to the server every <5 min and start/stop it from the app according to the app needs.

Comment: Actually, I have no control over how the server side is implemented and have to work accordingly to what I currently have. I guess this a discussion you have to make with Itay. you want me to tell him this?

Comment: This keep alive service will basically throw an empty request at the server every < 5 minutes in order to keep the session alive?

Comment: this means that I still need to have a corresponding URI address at server side to which I can make an "empty" call? And in the long term this will make an overload on the server when many users will validate their sessions all the time, so it's not recommended solution, right?

Comment: Right. Another problem that you'll have to deal with is connection problems with the server.

Comment: Right, that would be my next question. So basically if I have network problem, or the server went down. Then this keep-alive service will fail to do it's work and the session will become invalid. So I can't relay on the keep-alive service and still have to check I have a valid session before every call to the server.